# formating gtk label text using pango

Tags: c, string, formatting, glib

i am trying to load a text to gtk label formatted with pango but don't have a clue how to tell the text is a variable, here is my code

```
gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL (leyenda), <b><span size = '20000'> TextToSubstitute </span></b>;
```

TextoSubstitute is a variable wich receive text from an xml, i've tried everything to change the text but it asume what i place there as a string, any help?

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate strings in C as easily as you can in most languages with a "string" primitive type. Try something like this, using GLib functions:

```
char *markup = g_strconcat ("<b><span size='20000'>", textToSubstitute, "</span></b>", NULL);
/* or char *markup = g_strdup_printf ("<b><span size='20000'>%s</span></b>", textToSubstitute); */
gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL (leyenda), markup);
g_free (markup);
```